# OpenVPN: Create Client File with embeded or inline certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate, openvpn

I have read everything I can find on the Web, and I am having trouble creating a client file which works.

I am using **Tunnelblick** on my iMac as a client and have successfully imported an `.ovpn` file with something like the following:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote [ip-address] 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun

ca [inline]
cert [inline]
key [inline]

comp-lzo
verb 3

#   ca ca.crt
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

#   cert imac.crt
<cert>
-----BEGIN REQUEST-----

-----END REQUEST-----
</cert>

#   key imac.key
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
```

The `[ip address]` is a real ip address. The client is called **imac**, and I have comments where I *think* the appropriate data should come from.

The data was generated using **easy-rsa**, which generates the files, `imac.key`, `imac.crt` and `imac.cert`.

As I said, Tunnelblick successfully imports it, but when I try to connect I get the following messages:

```
OpenSSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
OpenSSL: error:140AD009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file:PEM lib
```

What do I do to get this to work?

Comment: SuperUser comes to mind. Also: Did you try native Tunnelblick configs, `.tlbk`?

Comment: @gf_ I haven’ tried `.tlbk`. Isn’t that just a folder with an .`ovpn` file inside?

Comment: @gf_ I’ll ask the question on SuperUser, and then delete it from here. Thanks

Comment: If I read the [docs](https://tunnelblick.net/cFileLocations.html#configuration-files) correctly, it's one file with all stuff inside, but I could be wrong on that.

Comment: By my reading of `openvpn`(8), inline files shouldn't have a separate `crt [inline]` option, just the tag-enclosure.

Comment: @womble Thanks for that. I have removed those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#   cert imac.csr
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

That is wrong.  That needs to be your **certificate** not the signing **request**. The signing request never gets used after the certificate is generated and can usually be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’ll get back in a few minutes after I’ve done some more research on getting the certificate.

Comment: I have rebuilt everything and copied the new data, including the `imac.crt` certificate across, but I am still getting the same issue. I have also edited the question to reflect your correction.

Comment: You've still got a CSR in there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The rest of the problems were due to the mess I had created in trying to get it all to work. I started again, and it’s all just fine.